# Can a jinn kill a human being?

Tags: jinn, human-body

Does a jinn have the ability to kill a human being?

And can they show us their real form if they want to?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know about of they're able to kill humans
But
If you sleep you can see them in sleep paralysis or just dreaming
They usually have a pitch black appearance and they have different shapes and sizes
I saw one with tree roots as feet and another one with horns
They have different appearances